# How do I get Durandal Router to stop messing with href="#"?

Tags: durandal, sammy.js

I'm getting started with Durandal JS and so far it's working great.

I have an issue though - ALL my links are being intercepted by Durandal's Router (Sammy JS under the hood). How can I get it to leave my links alone? `<a href="#"></a>`

If there is a Sammy JS-specific alternative to the hashtag as a href to make the browser think it's a link, that'd be awesome too.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16608815/1036187

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durandal's router.js is an optional component, so if you don't need it you can remove the script tag that loads sammy.js and remove `durandal/plugins/router` as dependencies in your AMDs.
If you need to partially protect some links from being handled by `router` then `guardRoute` http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/ is probably your best bet.

This assumes that you're running Durandal 1.2 and not the latest code from github (work in progress), where `router.js` just got completely rewritten and has no dependency on `sammy.js` any longer.

Comment: I do need it - hooking into guardRoute and handleInvalidRoute didn't help either. However, adding a Click event handler does seem to supress the 404 from Sammy.

Comment: So the goal is to provide a manual link to an existing route handled by router? Did you try using a trailing slash e.g. `<a href="#/">SO16918061 quick test</a>`?

Comment: the goal is to have a clickable link that does nothing :)

Comment: Interesting use case for an href :). What about <a href="#/" click="return false;">SO16918061 quick test</a>

Comment: I was prototyping, and after adding a Click event handler, it all works wonders again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following in anchor tags href elements:

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

and it seems to be working.